# Python Assignment of a Variable By Looping through a Range

Tags: python

The first two if statements should be identical...  The first one works, the second does not work. What is wrong with the second if statement?

```
    row=0
    tsig=0 
    InTrade=[] 

    for data_buy in stock_data['Buy']:  

       if data_buy == 1:
           tsig=1
           print(0)
       if stock_data['Buy'][row]==1:
           tsig=1
           print (1) 

       if tsig==1:    
           InTrade.append(1)
           print(3)
       if tsig==0:
           InTrade.append(0)
           print(4)
    row=row+1    
    print(stock_data['Buy'])
    stock_data['InTrade'] = InTrade
```

Answer (score 4):

`row=row+1` is outside the loop. It stays `0` in each iteration of the loop, and only becomes `1` after the loop is finished.

BTW - if you want to add an iteration index to a loop, you can(and should!) use `enumerate`:

```
for row, data_buy in enumerate(stock_data['Buy']):
    # loop body...
```